# Can you buff movement while wielding a (Golden) Hammer?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

I’m making Spirit presets for smashing with my friends, and the *Mini Mario w/Hammers* spirit’s trait of **Increased Hammer Duration** seemed like a fun build-around.

I have **Item Gravitation** and **Battering Items ↑**, but what it really needs is faster movement or further jump height.

Are all fighters locked into the same movement and jump when wielding a Hammer or Golden Hammer? Skills like **Lightweight** and **Movement ↑** seem to have no effect. Also, each character seems to have the same movement capabilities when swinging a hammer, so is it just hardcoded to always be the same?

Answer (score 1):

After some experimentation:

### Movement

- **Jump ↑** does nothing for height while wielding a hammer. It probably does nothing for jump speed either, but even if it does it’s very subtle.
- **Lightweight** also doesn’t help hammer jump height, but it seems to improve horizontal movement. Perhaps more importantly, it helps you grab
  hammers before others do. Probably better to prefer it over **Item Gravitation**.
- I have yet to test **Movement ↑**, **Dash Attack ↑** (slightly increases movement speed), **Landing Lag ↓**, **Floaty Jumps**, **Slow Super Armor**/**Armor Knight**, **Braking Ability ↑**, the jump/movement/fall speed-related Dojo Styles, or the the Rocket Belt or Super Leaf items.

  - I haven’t tested **Instadrop** or **Impact Run** either but I highly doubt they work while swinging.

### Improved Hammer damage

Didn’t test this yet, which might come from any of the following:

- **Battering Items ↑**
- **Weapon Attack ↑**
- **Trade-off Attack/Ability**
- **Critical-Health Attack/Stats**
- **Armor Knight**
- General spirit ATK stats
- **Toss & Meteor** might buff the knockback of the regular Hammer.
- **Equipment Style** from Dyntos’s dojo — maybe **Ninja Style** from Kat & Ana’s

That said — do you really *need* to buff Hammer offense?

### Other options

- **Item Gravitation** can help grab hammers first, but **Lightweight** also does, and then helps *after* getting the hammer. (**Movement Speed ↑** may also.)
- Unsure about **Shield Damage ↑**, but might also be moot with the hammer, just like damage buffs.
- You can’t get **Lifesteal** and **Increased Hammer Duration**.
- Savvy opponents may still hit you while you’re swingin’. **Improved Escape** can help if grabbed, and **Franklin Badge Equipped** helps against the projectiles that make it past the hammerhead.
- **Falling Immunity** stops tripping from banana peels, down tilts that outrange the hammer, etc. **Bury Immunity** is too situational.
- **Super Armor** is good, but you didn’t need me to tell you that.
- Nothing prevents counter specials from absolutely destroying the hammer wielder.
- **Strong Wind Resist/Immunity** don’t protect against windboxes — not even the Gust Bellows. :(
- **Giant** would be effective if you could guarantee a Hammer spawns early. But you can’t.
- **Back Shield Equipped** will not help very much, if at all.

Comment: If Jump+ doesn't increase jump height or speed, what does it do? (It does increase jump height, that's the main purpose of that spirit power. It's especially noticeable on characters that have a very short jump to begin with, such as Ganondorf.)

Comment: @MageXy They might mean that Jump+ does not increase height or speed *while wielding a hammer*.

Comment: @KamilDrakari Oh that makes sense.